# Finding path of 2 nodes in a binarysearchtree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, nodes

I have this code which should find the path between 2 nodes. The issue is that if node 2 is greater than node 1, it is unable to differentiate between it being a parent or right child and I do now how to correct this issue. I thought maybe swapping element2 and 1 would work but that just makes the order wrong.

```
def _find_path(self, element_1, element_2, nature):

    if element_1 !=None and element_2 != None:
        if element_1.key == element_2.key:
            self.list_path.append(element_1)
        else:
            if(element_1.key == self.root.key or element_2.key == self.root.key):
                if(element_2.key > element_1.key):
                    self.list_path.append(element_1)
                    self._find_path(element_1.rightChild, element_2, nature)
                if (element_2.key < element_1.key):
                    self.list_path.append(element_1)
                    self._find_path(element_1.leftChild, element_2, nature)
            else:
                    if(element_1.key < self.root.key and element_2.key < self.root.key or element_1.key > self.root.key and element_2.key > self.root.key):
                        if element_2.key > element_1.key:
                            self.list_path.append(element_1)
                            self._find_path(element_1.parent, element_2, nature)
                        if element_2.key < element_1.key:
                            self.list_path.append(element_1)
                            self._find_path(element_1.leftChild, element_2, nature)
                        else:
                            if element_1.key == element_2.key:
                               return [element_1]
                            res = self._find_path(element_1.leftChild, element_2,nature)
                            if res:
                                self.steps += 1
                                return [element_1] + res
                            res = self._find_path(element_1.rightChild, element_2,nature)
                            if res:
                                self.steps += 1
                                return [element_1] + res
                    else:
                        if(element_1.key < self.root.key and element_2.key > self.root.key):
                            self.list_path.append(element_1)
                            self._find_path(element_1.parent, element_2, nature)
                        else:
                            self.list_path.append(element_1)
                            self._find_path(element_1.parent, element_2, nature)
    return self.list_path
```

Comment: Wouldn't finding the path from the `root` to `element1` and then the path from `root` to `element2` and subtract the overlap in paths give you the path from `element1` to `element2`, e.g. if your path to element1 is `1, 3, 7` and your path to element2 is `1, 3, 9` then your path from element1 to element2 is just `7, 3, 9`. Your very heavily nested `if` statements makes me believe you've made this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: O......well how would I remove the overlaps?

Comment: reverse the path of element1 and check each node until you find one that is in the path to element2.